# ¿Por qué este código me devuelve siempre el valor de la última iteración?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Tengo este bucle en el que intento utilizar Geocoder desde un arreglo de direcciones, pero siempre me devuelve el valor de la última iteración (en el caso abajo expuesto siempre es 4 y aplicando siempre la misma imagen a cada marker).

He leido que debo insertar un *closure* para que guarde el valor de la variable *i* en cada iteración, pero no se donde aplicarle ya que es un concepto nuevo para mi.

El código es este:

```
geocoder.geocode({'address': event}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

      // aquí hago algunas cosas

      // este es mi bucle          
      for (var i=0; i < siteLoc.length; i++) {
        geocoder.geocode({'address': siteLoc[i]}, function(results, status) {
            (function(value) {
              var site = new google.maps.Marker({
                   map: resultsMap,
                   icon: '/assets/images/site' + value +'.png',
                   position: results[0].geometry.location
             });
             alert(value);
            })(i);
            // otras cosas aquí
          });
      }

    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
});
```

Comment: el famoso problema del closure en un loop.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: Puedes quitar código y dejar lo mínimo posible para reproducir el error? Por ejemplo solo el for y los alerts? Porque lo hacerlo yo y no puedo reproducirlo, en cada iteración obtengo un `i` distinto

Comment: Crear [funciones en ciclos](http://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop) es mala idea, eso incluye a los [IIFEs](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). Estoy seguro que puedes refactorizar el codigo y no tener que usar un IIFE dentro del ciclo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> He leído que debo insertar un closure para que guarde el valor de la variable i en cada iteracion

#### El Problema

Es al revés, el problema ***es*** que estas creando un closure en un bucle... recuerda cómo creas un closure: lo creas cuando creas una función dentro de otra.

Si ademas *almacenas* ese closure, este mantendrá la referencia a la variable `i` de la función padre. Y sera la misma variable para todas las ejecuciones del bucle.

Por ello cuando termine el bucle, todos los `callbacks` que esta almacenando *geocoder*, referencian a la misma variable: `i`... Cuyo valor es el máximo alcanzado por `i` (pues el `for` finalizo hace ya rato)...

Eliminado lo superfluo...

```
for (var i = 0; i < siteLoc.length; i++) {
  // esta función que sigue, es un callback, osea que queda almacenada y
  // es invocada mas adelante.. para ese entonces ya habrá terminado la 
  // ejecución del for, por cuanto i sera igual siteLoc.length.
  // por lo tanto todos los callbacks, reciben el valor maximo que alcanzo
  // la variable de i.
  //                                     AQUI ABAJO!
  geocoder.geocode({ 'address': site }, function(results, status) {

    // Donde pones el IIFE no es donde esta el problema, por ello no soluciona nada.
    (function(value) {         
      // algo con value, que siempre sera el máximo alcanzado por i
    })(i);

  });
}
```

Lo que sucede es que el closure mantiene una referencia a la variable externa, es una característica central de javascript.

#### Soluciones posibles:

#### Usar [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

`let` se diferencia de `var` en la forma que se conecta al *ambito* o scope, en el caso de un `for` cada iteración utiliza una version diferente de la variable, por lo que no hay closure que valga. Ten en cuenta que es una característica bastante nueva y no soportada por navegadores desactualizados.

```
for(let i; ... ) { // var x let ;= y olvidate del probelma

}
```

#### Usar [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Esta función tiene mas soporte, igual de efectiva pues cada iteración tiene su propia version de item e index.

```
siteLoc.forEach(function(item, index) {
    /// index es el i de tu for
    /// item, es el siteLoc[index]
    geocoder.geocode({'address': item}, function(results, status) {

    });
}
```

#### Declarar la función dentro de un IIEF

Un clásico, pero probablemente no pasara la prueba del analizador de código fuente, dirá que es una mala practica. En la actualidad, pienso que es correcto.

```
for (var i = 0; i < siteLog.length; i++) {

  // Aqui es donde el IIFE debia ir, por fuera
  (function(i_privado) {

    // aqui nace el cosure, pero no importa por que tiene su i_privado
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': siteLoc[i_privado] }, function(results, status) {

      var site = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: resultsMap,
        icon: '/assets/images/site' + i_privado + '.png',
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });

      // aqui el resto de tu codigo./
    });

  })(i);

}
```

#### Vieja Escuela, declara la función fuera del scope de `i`.

Esta es la mas *cross browser* y la que pasara por el *source analysis* sin problemas.

```
// en cualquier otro lado
function geocodeAddress(site, index) {
  // fijate que no usa siteLoc[i], pero recibe siteLoc[i]
  geocoder.geocode({ 'address': site }, function(results, status) {

    // tu codigo aqui.. el de siempre.
    // donde necesitabas i, usa index

  });
}

// luego invocas el bucle de esta forma. 
for(var i = 0; i < siteLoc.length; i++) {
  geocodeAddress(siteLoc[i], i);
}
```